# Javascript: Ajax call from PHP (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How should it works: I send one parameter to color.php. I made a variable (language) for it. Then it returns with a json object with 3 parameters: color, background color and text.

color.php

```
<?php
$result = Array("color"=>"", "bgcolor" => "", "text" => "");
$result["color"] = "rgb(".rand(0,255).",".rand(0,255).",".rand(0,255).")";
$result["bgcolor"] = "rgb(".rand(0,255).",".rand(0,255).",".rand(0,255).")";
switch($_GET["nyelv"]) {
    case "magyar":
        $result["text"] = "Hungarian text";
        break;
    case "angol":
        $result["text"] = "English tetx";
        break;
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

My javascript function:

```
$("#modosits").click(function(){
    var language =$("#nyelv").val();
    $.ajax({
      "url": "color.php",
      "type": "get",
      "data": language,
      "dataType": "json",
      "success": function(data) {
        $("#magyar").css("color", data.color);
        $("#magyar").css("background-color", data.bgcolor);
        $("#magyar").text(data.text);
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: What's the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing and what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: The color is not changing, the background color stays the same and the text is the same as well. I press the button (modosits) and nothing happens.

Comment: @Spoty, please move your problem description to your question by [edit]ing it. Comments are easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending data object to PHP but string language. In your PHP you are using `$_GET["nyelv"]`, send that property in your data, like `data: { nyelv: language}`.

```
 $("#modosits").click(function(){
    var language =$("#nyelv").val();
    $.ajax({
      "url": "color.php",
      "type": "get",
      "data": { nyelv: language },
      "dataType": "json",
      "success": function(data) {
        $("#magyar").css("color", data.color);
        $("#magyar").css("background-color", data.bgcolor);
        $("#magyar").text(data.text);
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use it:

```
$("#modosits").click(function(){
var myColor = $("#my_color").val();
var mybgColor= $("#mybgColor").val();
var mytext= $("#mytext").val();
$.ajax({
  "url": "color.php",
  "type": "get",
  "data": {
     color: myColor,
     bgcolor: mybgColor,
     text: mytext
  },
  "dataType": "json",
  "success": function(data) {
    $("#magyar").css("color", data.color);
    $("#magyar").css("background-color", data.bgcolor);
    $("#magyar").text(data.text);
  }
})
```

or you can use JSON.stringify(language) in client side 
and use json_decode(language) in server side

Comment: I would like to get those 3 things from the color.php not send them to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sending correct params and processing right and also sending back the correct data ( looks like all good on your codes) ...

What is missing is just a, lets say, translator !
try this piece of code :

```
"success": function(resp) {
    var data = JSON.parse(resp) ;
    $("#magyar").css("color", data.color);
    $("#magyar").css("background-color", data.bgcolor);
    $("#magyar").text(data.text);
  }
```